# Implicit Differentiation: Find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ of:

> $$4y^2+2=3x^2$$

### My Attempt

I attempted the probelm my first solving for the first derivative:

> $8y*y'=6x$
> $y'=\frac{3x}{4y}$

Then I tried it again; however I was a bit confused, and ended up getting

> $y''=\frac{6y-3x(2*y')}{16y^2}$

Would I substitute in the first derivative back in to get:

> $y''=\frac{6y-6x(\frac{3x}{4y})}{4y^2}$

and then finally

### Final Answer

$$y''=\frac{6y^2-9x^2}{4y^3}$$

Is my final answer correct, if not what is the correct answer please?

Comment: $8y y'$, not $4y y'$.

Comment: Your first step itself is wrong

Comment: $8yy^{'}=6x$ so $y^{'}=\frac{3x}{4y}$

Comment: @tilper Yeah I wrote that down in my notebook but forgot to here sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final answer is wrong and since you only ask for the correct final answer, here you go :
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{12y^2-9x^2}{16y^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

For future reference,
$F(x,y)=0$
$\frac{d^2[F(x,y)]}{dx^2}=-\frac
{\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)^2
-2·\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x\partial y}·\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}·\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}
+\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)^2}
{\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)^3}$

Comment: I don't think this will be very useful to the OP ...